# Problem due to incorrect libstdc++6

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, c++

When I do `sudo apt-get -f install` I am getting

```
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04) over (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6', which is different from other instances of package libstdc++6:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5

This is probably because of a conflict with libstdc++. (it happened when I was trying to install adobe acrobat)  How/where  do I find the right version of libstdc++6 and how to uninstall the broken version?

The output of `apt-cache policy libstdc++6:i386` is

```
libstdc++6:i386:
  Installed: 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu trusty/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11 8500
        500 http://mirror.****/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
     5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 500
        500 http://mirror.****/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
     5.3.1-14ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirror.****/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

(I have snipped the full IP address when I wrote **** above)

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures is
i386
```

Output of `dpkg -l libstdc++6` is

```
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
+++-====================-===============-===============-==============================================
iU  libstdc++6:amd64     5.4.0-6ubuntu1~ amd64           GNU Standard C++ Library v3
iF  libstdc++6:i386      8.1.0-5ubuntu1~ i386            GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

Output of `grep -v "#" /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://mirror**/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://mirror**/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

and so on so forth.
Will the problem get solved if I manually edit this file and change xenial to trusty (running `apt-get-clean` did not help fix this)

When I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libstdc++6:i386`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
              Breaks: libreoffice-core (<= 1:4.4.4~rc3-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
              Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and I cannot run `apt-get -f install` for the same reason as mentioned at the beginning of the thread. Let me know what can be done.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy libstdc++6:i386` output?

Comment: Any ideas/suggestions on what to do next to fix? As I am still lost. many thanks

Comment: I’m not sure what’s going wrong here. Could you show the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and of `dpkg -l libstdc++6`? Please [edit] your question to add the results, they’ll be more readable than in a comment.

Comment: I have answered above by re-editing my original message. Hopefully now it is clearer.

Comment: Again another plea for SOS  as I cannot forge ahead without a fix to this problem

Comment: Your sources.list seems to be of xenial. I'll rather suggest you to open Software and Updates app and refresh the repository information. Also is going EOL within a week. Consider upgrading to 16.04 or 18.04+

Comment: @kulfy I'm seeing references to trusty *and* xenial in the output. My guess is they *drastically* screwed up and caused a [Frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is badly messed up. You have somehow ended up with Xenial (16.04) repos enabled on your Trusty (14.04) system. This is obviously causing weird package conflicts like this.

Just fix/clean up your repository configuration, run `apt-get clean` and everything should start working again.

Comment: I ran apt-get clean, but it did not make any difference (with no diagnostic message) and I still get the same error when I run apt-get -f install

Comment: @Shantanu Have you fixed the `sources.list` first?

Comment: Yes, but even after that  apt-get clean runs without any  message.  I still get the same error with apt-get -f install (Note that the output of  apt-cache policy libstdc++6:i386 now only shows the trusty packages.However output of dpkg -l libstdc++6 is same as before). Do I need to remove the newer version of libdst++ which has been installed? Thanks for all the help

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you have the xenial package installed. Yes, you need to get rid of that. `apt-get install --reinstall libstdc++6:i386` should help.

Comment: I ran the above command, but still a problem (see the original message where the full output is given)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to remove the newer (16.04) libstdc++6 package

> sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends libstdc++6:amd64

Download the libstdc++6 version for trusy (14.04) from the package repo here
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libstdc++6/4.8.2-19ubuntu1

Extract the package and Copy the 3 files from the downloaded package to the respective location

> sudo cp libstdc++.so.6.0.19 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
>
> sudo cp -P libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
>
> sudo cp -P libstdc++6 /usr/share/doc/

apt-get should be working now, reinstall libstdc++6 to fix dependencies

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall libstdc++6
> sudo apt-get -f install

You should now be back to normal